# What are these warnings for minitoc package?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, warnings, minitoc

I'm using a `scrreprt` document class to write my lecture notes in a condensed form for easy reviewing later. I organized the `main.tex` in a modular file and I downloaded, installed and loaded the `minitoc` package because I wanted to have a mini-TOC at the beginning of each chapter. However, when I compile with pdfLaTeX I get 8 warnings: some are not that important (`Italian not defined, using English instead`), others are perplexing:

```
Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0030
(minitoc(hints))                --- The \part command is altered 
(minitoc(hints))                after minitoc.

Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0023
(minitoc(hints))                --- It may be the consequence 
(minitoc(hints))                of loading the ``hyperref'' package.

Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0028
(minitoc(hints))                --- The \chapter command is altered 
(minitoc(hints))                after minitoc.
```

Are these serious warnings? Do I *need* to get them fixed? It's not impeding me to obtain a final *.pdf file, but I wonder if it is signaling a much serious underlying problem that I'm missing. After all, it's the first time I'm using `minitoc` package.
I've also noticed there is a *.mtc0, *.mtc1, *.mtc2, *.mtc3 etc that are created after compilation. If I erase them, next time there'll be *.mtc4 and so forth.

- I'm on a Debian 7.3 (KDE desktop) machine, with
- TeX Live 2013 installed "manually" (ie with a dummy *.deb package, not via repository) and
- Kile editor 2.1.0.

Here's a minimal working example:

1) `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts} 

\usepackage[math,bible]{blindtext}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH} 
\usepackage[italian]{cleveref} 
\usepackage[italian]{minitoc}


%opening
\title{M.T.N.}
\author{Myself}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\mbox{}
\cleardoublepage

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\input{Err_w1}
\end{document}
```

2) `Err_w1`

```
\chapter{Topic One}

\minitoc
\clearpage
\section{First Topic}
\blindmathpaper

\section{Second Topic}
\blindtext

\subsection{Second Topic, first subsection}
\blindtext
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning message `Italian not defined, using English instead` is issued by `blindtext`, so you can safely ignore it (and it won't appear in a real document).

For the annoying messages issued by `minitoc`, you can use the `silence` package:

```
\usepackage{silence}

\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0023}
\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0028}
\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0030}

\WarningFilter{blindtext}{} % this takes care of the `blindtext` messages
```

The package works by telling it what messages to ignore, based on the information string and the start of the message. With these lines, only the message

```
Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0024
(minitoc(hints))                Some hints have been written 
(minitoc(hints))                in the wobby.log file.
```

appears. You can disable it, too, in the same way.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{silence}

\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0023}
\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0028}
\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0030}

\WarningFilter{blindtext}{} % this takes care of the `blindtext` messages

\usepackage[math,bible]{blindtext}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH} 
\usepackage[italian]{cleveref} 
\usepackage[italian]{minitoc}


%opening
\title{M.T.N.}
\author{Myself}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\mbox{}
\cleardoublepage

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\chapter{Topic One}

\minitoc
\clearpage
\section{First Topic}
\blindmathpaper

\section{Second Topic}
\blindtext

\subsection{Second Topic, first subsection}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

You could disable *all* warnings by `minitoc`, but I wouldn't recommend it. Just disable those warnings you know for sure are innocuous.

Comment: Mmm...seems like I'll have to download/install another package. Will let you know how that goes.

Answer (score 8):

In the [`minitoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) documentation, part I “User’s Manual”, a chapter “Messages” exists (chapter 5 at time of writing), where you can read more information about these warnings. *(Alas, this documentation is missing in MiKTeX, read online on TeXdoc.net: [`minitoc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/minitoc).)*

- Warning `W0030`:

  > Some packages alter the sectionning commands, like `\part`. Most of them should be loaded *before* the `minitoc` package. The `hyperref` package, even if it is loaded *before* the `minitoc` package (as recommended), alters the sectionning commands in an `\AtBeginDocument`, so this message is always printed when you use the `hyperref` package with `minitoc`, but then it is harmless.
- Warning `W0028` is the same for `\chapter`.
- Also Warning `W0023` is essentially the same, but a general warning for changed sectionning commands:

  > Some sectionning commands have been altered *after* the loading of the `minitoc` package. The `hyperref` package does that, but it is harmless. For other packages or user-made alterations, it is recommended to alter the sectionning commands only *before* loading the `minitoc` package.

egreg already wrote, how to disable these harmless warnings.

I got BTW with your code another harmless message declared as warning:

```
Package minitoc(hints) Warning: W0024
(minitoc(hints)) Some hints have been written
(minitoc(hints)) in the ⟨document⟩.log file.
```

Other than egreg I want to recommend you: In the *final* state of your document writing you could add the package option `nohints`, which disables all these in most cases harmless, more informative warnings.

---

Another hint: Search also in the `minitoc` documentation for “KOMA-Script”, because with some options respective configurations you have to be precautious.

> […]  with the KOMA-Script classes […], it may sometimes be necessary to use the following options or commands, […] The efficiency of the following options depends on the options given to these KOMA-Script classes (parindent option, parskip option and variants).
>   […]
>   For the KOMA-Script classes, with the commands `\ktightmtctrue` (or the `k-tight` package option) and `\ktightmtcfalse` (or the `k-loose` package option, which is the default), the mini-tables will have less (tight) or more (loose) space between contents lines.

> Note that the same problems appear if you use one of the […] KOMA-Script classes with some options (`liststotoc`, `liststotocnumbered`, `bibtotoc`, `bibtotocnumbered`, and `idxtotoc`). The solutions are the same ones.

Comment: I think `[nohints]` is the best solution, thanks!