# Change chapter title format in scrreprt without titlesec?

Tags: koma-script, titlesec, report

I'm working with `scrreprt` and I have loaded `minitoc` to have a short TOC after each chapter title. However when I give the `\chapter` command I get:

> 1 Chapter Title

I'd like to have:

> Chapter 1
>
> Chapter Title

like in the ordinary `report` document-class (which I'm not using because I like the page size and fonts of the `scrreprt` doc-class).

I've seen in [this other thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159869/koma-script-scrreprt-chapter-heading-size-customisation) the following piece of code but it requires the `titlesec` package. I'm not familiar with that package, besides I think I would get errors and warnings on top of what I'm [already getting now](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166910/package-minitochints-warnings-after-compiling).

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
\scalebox{4}{\color{gray}\thechapter\autodot}\enskip}}
```

Can someone please help me get the result I'm wanting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the `titlesec` package for that. It suffices to add the option `chapterprefix=true` when loading `scrreprt`.

Taking the code from [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167021/27635) at your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166910/27635) and adding the above option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{silence}

\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0023}
\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0028}
\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0030}
\WarningFilter{minitoc(hints)}{W0024}

\WarningFilter{blindtext}{} % this takes care of the `blindtext` messages

\usepackage[math,bible]{blindtext}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH}
\usepackage[italian]{cleveref}
\usepackage[italian]{minitoc}


%opening
\title{M.T.N.}
\author{Myself}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\mbox{}
\cleardoublepage

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\chapter{Topic One}

\minitoc
\clearpage
\section{First Topic}
\blindmathpaper

\section{Second Topic}
\blindtext

\subsection{Second Topic, first subsection}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps my answer is interesting, too: [KOMA-Script (scrbook): onecolumn table of contents & minitoc in twocolumn document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151330).

Comment: Looks cool but I'd prefer making the most of the whole width of the page.